# Coverting bootstrap theme to word press

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am pretty new to wordpress, I want to convert a bootstrap theme into wordpress,i dont know if this question is a stupid one. This is the code in my functions file

```
 <!---This is my functions.php file---->
<?php 
  add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
  function new2w_theme_styles(){
     wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '');
     wp_enqueue_style( 'essentials_css', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/css/essentials.css');
     wp_enqueue_style( 'layout_css', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/css/layout.css');
     wp_enqueue_style( 'scheme_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/color_scheme/blue.css');
     wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_forms', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-forms-v2.css');
     wp_enqueue_style( 'pack_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/pack_realestate.css');
     wp_enqueue_style( 'header-1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/header-1.css');
     wp_enqueue_style( 'style_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');    
  }
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'new2w_theme_styles');
   function new2w_theme_js(){
     wp_enqueue_scripts('bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js',array('jquery'), '', true);
     wp_enqueue_scripts('script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'), '', true);    
   }
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'new2w_theme_js');
?>
```

Please how can I perform this same loop task for another section of my static page,I have looped through 3 images with this code, I have also created corresponding post in my admin panel;

```
<?php if( have_posts()) : while( have_posts()) : the_post();?>
       HTML GOES HERE
  <?php endwhile; endif;?>
<?
```

I want to use this same method to loop through another image grid of 4 with the `get_the_post_thumbnail()` function, how do I manage post for this.?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 
this question belongs on [WordPress Development | StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question properly; are you wanting to loop through yours posts and then display the featured images for them? If you're wanting to loop through through separate posts you can either take advantage of post categories, or create a Custom Post Type. These will then need to be specified inside your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the contents of the bootstrap CSS file and paste the style definitions to your theme (in dashboard, go to Design / Customizer / Additional CSS and paste the code there).

However to apply the style classes to the correct WordPress generated DOM elements, you either have to apply class names to those DOM elements or rename the style classes such that they fit to the DOM elements' names. This approach could still clash with other CSS files anyways.

Comment: I dont know if I get your answer, I have already copied my bootsttrap css into the wordpress's css file, my page renders coreectly, all I want to do is repeat  a task, but this time different images from the previous image on the post. How can ```get_the_post_thumbnail()``` know the right image to render